# is it possible to list LAN names when DNS is managed by ext router?

Tags: networking, dns, ip-address

I wish to know the computer name associated with a known ip-address.
The DNS is managed by my router (WIND3 webcube) and I can see the resolved name using the browser (http://192.168.1.1)
Nevertheless, I wish to read the LAN computer names by command line from the console.
I've tried <ping -r 192.168.1.255> then <arp -a> as suggested by Bodo; this has shown all IPs & relevant MACs on the LAN except my own; the only hostname shown has been the router name corresponding to 192.168.1.1 - half question has been answered, now I have a way to discover remote IPs on the LAN by console.
In addition, using <nmap -sn 192.168.1.0/24>, I can see the full list of IPs on the LAN but still no hostnmes.

At the moment the best solution is running this script:
for x in {101..110}
do nslookup 192.168.1.$x | grep name
done

that shows all active names and relevant IPs (reversed)

Comment: see https://serverfault.com/q/7056

Comment: I suppose I badly explain what I need - sorry. I try to better explain. I know that the DHCP range is 192.168.1.100 ... 192.168.1.110 because I set it on the router . The best could be a command showing the list of IPaddr & hostname for each host connected, but it would also be acceptable a command for single enquiry i.e. IPaddr corresponding to an hostname or the reverse, hostname corresponding to an IPaddr. At the moment "dig -x <IPaddr>" works for my own IPaddr and for DHCP server IPaddr only, giving my own hostname and the DHCP server's name. For all other IPaddr it returns blank names.

Comment: Please don't use comments to add information, [edit] your question instead. You might have to specify `@server`, see [man dig](https://linux.die.net/man/1/dig). I was not able to use `nslookup`'s `ls` or `dig`'s `axfr` to get a full listing from my router. Querying single addresses works.

Answer (score 2):

**workarounds**(*using ping, arp table and scans*) that should work in most networks but might not report all devices(*reports **only** those devices that echo/respond to the ping*).

##### With `ping` and `arp`

[`ping`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man8/ping.8.html)(*for a short while*) the broadcast IP address(*i.e. the highest, last and unusable IP address in your sub-net e.g. `192.168.1.255`*) which will in turn result in ping packets being sent to every possible IP address on your network like so:

```bash
ping -b 192.168.1.255
```

Then, run an [`arp`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man4/arp.4freebsd.html)(*Address Resolution Protocol*) request like so:

```bash
arp -a
```

##### With `nmap`

From [`man nmap`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man1/nmap.1.html):

```
-sn (No port scan)
  This option tells Nmap not to do a port scan after host discovery,
  and only print out the available hosts that responded to the host
  discovery probes. This is often known as a “ping scan”.
```

So, you can use it on your network like so:

```bash
nmap -sn 192.168.1.0/24
```

Where `192.168.1.0`(*the first unusable IP address i.e. `0`*) is your network address and `24` is your sub-net mask.

Answer (score 1):

To get the name for a single known IP address from the router you can use

```
dig @router -x ipaddress +short
```

for example

```
dig @192.168.1.1 -x 192.168.1.100 +short
```

see [man dig](https://linux.die.net/man/1/dig)

I was not able to use `dig`'s query type `axfr` or `nslookup`'s `ls` command to get a full listing from my router. This might be a permissions issue.

Of course you can use shell programming to run `dig` in a loop for a range of IP addresses.

Comment: You probably can do something like `seq -f "192.168.1.%g" 1 254 | xargs -n 1 dig @192.168.1.1 +noall +answer +time=1 -x`